# org.apache.http.entity.mime shows error when facebooksdk lib is added to project

Tags: android, facebook

when facebooksdk lib is not added to project it working fine to upload images on server !
but when add facebooksdk lib to my project it shows following error :

```
Path: /Users/mac/Downloads/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1/facebook/libs/android-support-v4.jar    
Length: 349252    
SHA-1: 6128xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the jar from the Facebook project's libs folder into yours.

You were getting an error because there were two different versions of the same library associated with your project. The above will fix this by having both project's use the Facebook version of the library.